# What happens to the charge which enters the positive terminal of the battery in a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity

SO basically , I know that a battery creates potential difference or V in a circuit to flow, by doing work on the charge(electrons) . The motion of the charge(electrons) is from the -ve or negative end to the +ve or positive end(i.e- the positive terminal of the battery). SO what happens to that charge(electron) when it reaches the **+ve or positive terminal of the cell** , **Is it consumed by the cell?** or **Are the properties of the charge changed to make it flow again from the -ve terminal to the +ve terminal?**, OR **Does the battery's -ve terminal produce electrons after consuming them?**